# Add Authentication headers in $.post() ajax JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My Ajax post request is like this :-

```
     $.post("http://localhost:XXXX/api/TEST/Post", { "HtmlText": htmlDataFromEditor, "Standard": Standard, "Subject": Subject, "Chapter": Chapter, "Created": "1", "Updated": "0", "Deleted": "0" }, function (data) {
           alert(data);
     });
```

I want to add the header to this post request.

How can i add the header?

I dont want to use $.ajax().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.post("http://localhost:XXXX/api/TEST/Post", 
   { "HtmlText": htmlDataFromEditor, "Standard": Standard, "Subject": Subject, "Chapter": Chapter, "Created": "1", "Updated": "0", "Deleted": "0" }, 
   function (data) {
       alert(data);
   },
   'html' /*add header type here*/
);
```

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm).

Comment: I have gone through the Reference you provided. But no result. Can you help me, I want to add the 'Authorization' in header of the ajax post request.